Number theory of Minkowski theory
While studying Minkowski theory from Neukirch's book, it is said:

Given $K|\mathbb Q$, a number field, $j:K\rightarrow K_{\mathbb C}:=\prod_{\tau}\mathbb C:a\mapsto ja=(\tau a)_{\tau}$ where $\tau:K\rightarrow \overline {\mathbb Q} \subset \mathbb C$ are embeddings. $$F:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C : z \mapsto \overline z$$ acts on both $K_{\mathbb C}$ and $\{\tau\}$, altogether defines an involution $$F:K_{\mathbb C}\rightarrow K_{\mathbb C} : z=(z_{\tau})_\tau\mapsto ((Fz)_\tau)_\tau=(\overline z_{\overline\tau})_\tau $$

So far so good.
We define a linear map in the way $$\mathrm{Tr}:K_{\mathbb C}\rightarrow \mathbb C : z=(z_\tau)_\tau\mapsto \sum_{\tau}\tau(z)$$
Then it is said - it is $F$ invariant. I'm confused: what does it mean by "$F$" invariant? Does this mean $F\circ \mathrm{Tr}=\mathrm{Tr}$ or $\mathrm{Tr}\circ F=\mathrm{Tr}$ (as $F$ acts both on $\mathbb C$ and $K_{\mathbb C}$)?
For example, say $[K:\mathbb Q]=3$, then embeddings be $\{id, \tau_1, \tau_2\}$, and also assume $\overline \tau_1=\tau_2$, and pick $(a+ib, x+iy, m+in)\in K_{\mathbb C}$, then $$(a+ib, x+iy, m+in)\xrightarrow{F}(a-ib,m-in,x-iy)\xrightarrow{\mathrm{Tr}}(a+m+x)-i(b+y+n)\neq \mathrm{Tr}(a+ib, x+iy, m+in)$$ $$(a+ib, x+iy, m+in)\xrightarrow{\mathrm{Tr}}(a+m+x)+i(b+y+n)\xrightarrow 
 {F}(a+m+x)-i(b+y+n) \neq \mathrm{Tr}(a+ib, x+iy, m+in).$$

Neither. It means $F\circ {\rm Tr} = {\rm Tr}\circ F$. Another common word for this property is that ${\rm Tr}$ is $F$-equivariant. However, it is also literally $F$-invariant in the following sense: if $F$ is an operator that acts invertibly on two groups $A$ and $B$, then it also acts on ${\rm Hom}(A,B)$ by $F(\sigma) = F\circ \sigma\circ F^{-1}$ for $\sigma \in {\rm Hom}(A,B)$. You might want to check that this is indeed a left action (the purpose of the inverse is to ensure that this is the case). A homomorphism from $A$ to $B$ is invariant under this action if and only if it is equivariant in the sense just defined.
